# NSInvalidArgumentException in RNFBMessagingSerializer with Firebase Messaging on iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am encountering a crash in my React Native app that involves Firebase Messaging, specifically within the `[RNFBMessagingSerializer remoteMessageUserInfoToDict:]` method.

**Crash Report Summary:**

```
**+[RNFBMessagingSerializer remoteMessageUserInfoToDict:]
NSInvalidArgumentException - -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance <address>**

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xec69c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2bc80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x17cfdc +[NSObject(NSObject) _copyDescription]
3  CoreFoundation                 0x31e08 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 0x172950 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  meatigo                        0x1595c8 +[RNFBMessagingSerializer remoteMessageUserInfoToDict:] + 108 (RNFBMessagingSerializer.m:108)
6  meatigo                        0x1573dc -[RNFBMessagingUNUserNotificationCenter userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:] + 157 (RNFBMessaging+UNUserNotificationCenter.m:157)
7  meatigo                        0xbbc80 FCMSwizzleDidReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler + 552 (FIRMessagingRemoteNotificationsProxy.m:552)
8  UIKitCore                      0x3a1f88 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x210958 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x20f504 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]
11 UIKitCore                      0x20f150 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:]
12 UIKitCore                      0x18bc78 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask
13 UIKitCore                      0x21314c __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke
14 UIKitCore                      0x13abe0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:]
15 UIKitCore                      0x139658 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]
16 UIKitCore                      0x138fc0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x138e90 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke
18 UIKitCore                      0x138d98 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x138620 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion
20 UIKitCore                      0x1382d0 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x4bc0a8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.225
22 UIKitCore                      0x137454 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:]
23 UIKitCore                      0x1372c4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]
24 UIKitCore                      0x24fa48 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]
25 UIKitCore                      0x24f7e0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:]
26 FrontBoardServices             0xf6d4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:]
27 FrontBoardServices             0xf570 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108
28 FrontBoardServices             0xe19c -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:]
29 FrontBoardServices             0x19f8c __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x7d48 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct
32 FrontBoardServices             0xa520 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
33 FrontBoardServices             0xa4a0 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible]
34 FrontBoardServices             0xa378 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
35 CoreFoundation                 0x3712c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
36 CoreFoundation                 0x363a8 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
37 CoreFoundation                 0x34bbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0
38 CoreFoundation                 0x33898 __CFRunLoopRun
39 CoreFoundation                 0x33478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
40 GraphicsServices               0x34f8 GSEventRunModal
41 UIKitCore                      0x22c62c -[UIApplication _run]
42 UIKitCore                      0x22bc68 UIApplicationMain
43 meatigo                        0x83b0 main + 8 (main.m:8)
44 ???                            0x1c827adcc (Missing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMFAR.png)
```

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: **to fix the firebase messaging crash**
go to the path:**/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingSerializer.m**

    // message.mutableContent
  ````-if (apsDict[@"mutable-content"] != nil && [apsDict[@"mutable-content"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) { 
 +if (apsDict[@"mutable-content"] != nil && [apsDict[@"mutable-content"] intValue] == 1) {````
       message[@"mutableContent"] = @([RCTConvert BOOL:apsDict[@"mutable-content"]]);
     }

Comment: already using it but still facing crash

Comment: it works in my case